# Why does new layer get ignored in modified pretrained pytorch model?

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model

I am trying to add a classification layer to a pre-trained Bert model.  I've tried a few things people have posted online like:

```py
mod = list(model.children())

mod.pop()

mod.append(torch.nn.Linear(768, num_classes))

new_classifier = torch.nn.Sequential(*mod)

model.classifier = new_classifier
```

When I print out the model I can see the new layer there in the summary, but when I try to train or predict pytorch just ignores that new layer.  Anyone know what's going on with that?  I'm new to pytorch.

Also tried for the last 2 lines:

```py
new_classifier = torch.nn.Sequential(*list(mod))

model = new_classifier
```

but this is throwing a 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error.

Answer (score 0):

From your post, it seems like you are trying to replace the last layer of a model. Try this and see if it works as a work around

```
new_classifier = torch.nn.Sequential(*(list(model.children())[:-1]), nn.Linear(768, num_classes))
model = new_classifier
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately when I then pass new_classifier data I get an error that 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: Also, this was another suggestion, to simply just add another layer by adding the line: "model.classifier = torch.nn.Linear(768, num_classes)", but then when I pass it data it ignores this line and just returns the 768 dim embedding (though no error)

Comment: Could you please include the full error and more details?

Comment: Here's more error details: 
~/DNABERT/src/transformers/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, head_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask)
    409 
    410             layer_outputs = layer_module(
--> 411                 hidden_states, attention_mask, head_mask[i], encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask
    412             )
    413             hidden_states = layer_outputs[0]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I needed to do something like: class PosModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PosModel, self).__init__()
        
        self.base_model = model
        self.linear = nn.Linear(768, 1213) 
        
    def forward(self, input_ids):
        outputs = self.base_model(input_ids)
        # You write you new head here
        outputs = self.linear(outputs[1])
        
        return outputs

new_model = PosModel()